# clicking the links within a pdf rendered by ng2-pdf viewer doesnt work

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, angular5

I have an angular component and I am rendering a pdf using ng2-pdf-viewer. how ever clicking the links within the pdf it is not navigating to that section .

`<pdf-viewer [src]="documentlocation" [render-text]="true" style="display: block;"></pdf-viewer>`

this is how i render the pdf on my compoent .any help is appreciated
thank you

+++++++++++++++

i have created a small project to demonstarate the problem . github.com/prasanthmp500/pdf2example . you can checkout the project and run ng serve .the type in the browser localhost:4200 the page displays a pdf file . how ever clicking links within that rendered pdf works

Comment: Did you give the attention to the documentation?https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer/blob/master/README.md#external-link-target Did you tried!? If it's not working pls create in stack blitz and mention the link pls!

Comment: Hi Ravi thank you for the reply . its better i create in stack blitz

Comment: i have created a small project and shown the problem. https://github.com/prasanthmp500/pdf2example . you can checkout the project and run ng serve .the type in the browser http://localhost:4200 the page displays a pdf file . how ever clicking links within that rendered pdf works